# how to map tensor to it's indices in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a 2D tensor with shape (size, size), and I want to get 2 new tensors that containing the original tensors row index and column index.
So if size is 2, I want to get
[[0, 0], [1, 1]] and [[0, 1], [0, 1]]

What's tricky is that size is another tensor whose value can only be known when running the graph in a tensorflow Session. 
How can I do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [tf.meshgrid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/meshgrid).

Here's an example:

```python
shape = tf.shape(matrix)
R, C = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(shape[0]), tf.range(shape[1]), indexing='ij')
```

`matrix` is your 2D tensor, `R` and `C` contain your row and column indices, respectively. Note that this can be slightly simplified if your matrix is square (only one `tf.range`).